# PyCharm Focus on Active Task

Tags: pycharm

Eclipse as part of the Mylyn integration has the "Focus On Active Task" button which, when clicked, will restrict the outline view to only show files that have been opened as part of the currently active task.  Screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

I was wondering if PyCharm has something similar.  I often will accidentally close files before switching task contexts, and then when I go back to the task I have no way of knowing which files I opened as part of that task (it only re-opens any files that were open at the time the task was closed), whereas in Eclipse, when I click the "Focus On Active Task" button the files I opened are shown in the project explorer.

If it matters, PyCharm Community 2016.2 is what I'm using.

Comment: I've been working with IntelliJ products for a long while now, but never saw something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The closest PyCharm feature I know of is switching the file browser to `Changed Files` mode, in which only the changed files are listed:

[image]

It won't automatically open the files - the editor windows remain the ones you had open when you closed the project, but at least it makes it easy to quickly open the changed files.

Comment: Hmm, when I switch to a task and then pick "Changed Files" mode, I see "Nothing to show".

Comment: Well, were there changed files in that task when you closed it?